# p-value for correlation

Tags: correlation, p-value, monte-carlo

I tried to calculate it using simple Monte-Carlo. However, I am not convinced in the correctness of the results, so wanted to double-check. For vectors of length 10,000, how high Pearson R do I need, to get p-value of 0.1%? Also, is there another way to arrive at these numbers without using simulation, i.e. in a closed form?

The null hypothesis is that the correlation is effectively 0, i.e. that the 2 time series are uncorrelated.

Comment: Exactly what test are you using?  What is the null hypothesis and what is the alternative?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: If the problem is correlating two time series, note that Pearson correlation takes no account of dependence structure. The correlation would be the same if the values were shuffled out of time order, so any P-values are somewhere between irrelevant and spurious as they ignore the fact and the consequences of the data  being time series.

Comment: Sure, but I am calculating the correlation between the 2 series, not within one of them, so if you apply a shuffle to only one of them, then the correlation between them changes.

Comment: Correct, but not an objection to the argument. The argument is that at best the correlation takes no account of the data being time series. That should be important to you unless your model is that time series are white noise.

Comment: Well, to be more precise, they are diffs of time series, i.e. x(t+1)-x(t), not x(t).

Comment: That doesn't make anything easier here. A plain Pearson correlation may be a useful descriptive statistic for you, but no meaningful P-value can be produced that ignores the data generating process.

Comment: That's very interesting, thank you very much for your input. Can you please elaborate? Perhaps in an answer rather than comment? Is it not valid to assume x(i+1)-x(i) is independent of x(j+1)-x(j)? If we assume that, how do we get a meaningful p-stat for the correlation then?

Comment: I think you have to simulate realisations of your time series under your assumed model to get a sampling distribution for Pearson correlation. If you don't have an assumed model for the data generating process I don't know how you can solve the problem. In general it is not at all valid to assume that differences in a time series are independent: as implied at the outset that comes under the heading of dependence structure. But you can look at the autocorrelations of the differences to check how far that is violated in your data.

Comment: Another quite different kind of answer is that you look at time series literature in general they don't seem to do what you are trying. (I am not a time series expert; I just know enough to warn you of some pitfalls here.)

Comment: That's great, thank you very much. So, what is something that they do in time series literature, any useful pointers? Btw, do you have any ideas how can I go about simulating my data more accurately in Monte Carlo for better p-values? What properties of my realized data do I use (mean, variance, autocorrelation)? The first 2 should not be relevant for correlation, right?

Comment: Also, how do I generate a random time series in python with specified autocorrelation?